# How to store additional user info?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Here's the issue at hand: I have developed an ASP.NET MVC3 application using Razor. I have also implemented a custom membership provider and overridden the ValidateUser() method. Within, I query my db and get a lot of user information in addition to the password auth.

At the moment, I am pushing this information, i.e. companyId, to static properties of a class. This works and I can display/use this information throughout my app. The problem arises when a user closes their browser tab. Upon re-opening the app, the user is authenticated via a cookie, so they don't need to re-login; however, those static variables are blown away.

So guys and girls, how would/do you conquer this issue? Should I append the extra info to the session cookie? Or perhaps a better solution?

Comment: @Chase, a Profile Provider is supposed to be used for this (just like the Membership Provider is for accounts). Why won't what work?

Comment: Are these "static variables" held in session or at the application level?

Comment: Microsoft advises against using the ProfileProvider for new ASP.NET/MVC applications: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595053/add-support-for-the-sql-table-profile-provider-in-asp-net-4-web-applications

Comment: @Joel: At the application level now.

Comment: @Chase That old post advises against using the `SqlProfileProvider`, and says the Profile Feature itself will not be expanded. That should hardly come as news to anyone. :) If you write your own simple Profile Provider, you're not violating any advice. The Profile Feature is still the simplest way to store profile data, unless you want to take the ten minutes to brew your own custom profile management solution coupled with the Membership Feature.

Comment: @bzlm: Ah, thanks for setting me straight. I will take a stab at a custom profileprovider. Thanks and sorry for the oversight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ProfileProvider` in ASP.NET.

Comment: I was wrong about my previous comment! Errr I mean, test post, please ignore ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For application level variables, they are going to be subject to application pool recycles and similar "simulated" restarts related to users starting all over. These variables should be completely independent of user usage and should be able to be recreated easily. If you have variables that are user dependent or that can't be restored easily without some sort of outside intervention then you will definitely need a different method of storage.

If the data is user specific, storing it in the session cookie is probably the best idea. If the data is user-related but branches multiple users it should be stored in a database or a flat file somewhere. If the data has nothing to do with users specifically then it should just be in a database or configuration file.

Comment: Ok awesome, so I should hunt down the methods that store the session info and override them, yes?

Comment: Session is not the best solution because it is not scaling very well

Comment: @Jenea: I'm not sure what you mean by it not scaling very well. What should scale and how should it scale?